# Were sub-menu lists of admin panel deleted?

Tags: 9

I installed Drupal 9.3. In its administration panel, I don't see drop-down sub-menu lists I saw in a Drupal 8.9 site, where I could hover the cursor at any of the first level menu items (for example, *Content* or *Structure*).

Has sub-menu lists of the administration panel been removed in Drupal 9.x?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drop-down menus on hover are a feature of the [Admin Toolbar](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_toolbar) module. Check if it is enabled, or install if missing.

Comment: Was it just admin_toolbar or was it the admin_toolbar_tools sub-module?

Comment: I usually just add all the submodules. Not sure wether OP is aware of the finer grain options available.